# How to idiomatically print currency in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, currency, number-formatting

I'm using the following:

```
(defn dollars [input] (str "$" (format "%.2f" input)))
```

(which doesn't do the commas)

But I think there must be a method using [`pprint/cl-format`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.pprint/cl-format).

My question is: **How to idiomatically print currency in Clojure?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have more to work with money, than just formatting it, you might consider using https://github.com/clojurewerkz/money (see the section *Formatting*), which wrapps `joda-money`.  This not only covers formatting, but also other common problems like rounding.

```
user=> (mf/format (ma/amount-of mc/USD 10000))
"$10,000.00"
user=> (mf/format (ma/amount-of mc/USD 10000) java.util.Locale/GERMANY)
"USD10.000,00"
```

**edit**

You can pass the `amount-of` means of rounding.  E.g.

```
user=> (mf/format (ma/amount-of mc/USD 10.111111111111111))

ArithmeticException Scale of amount 10.11111111111111 is greater than the scale of the currency USD  org.joda.money.Money.of (Money.java:74)

user=> (mf/format (ma/amount-of mc/USD 10.111111111111111 (java.math.RoundingMode/HALF_DOWN)))
"$10.11"
```

Comment: This option doesn't seem to scale:
core=> (format (clojurewerkz.money.amounts/amount-of clojurewerkz.money.currencies/USD 1181.2442721929447))

ArithmeticException Scale of amount 1181.2442721929447 is greater than the scale of the currency USD  org.joda.money.Money.of (Money.java:74)

Comment: @hawkeye see edit, you can pass a rounding mode to `amount-of`

Answer (score 2):

See also Bankster: https://github.com/randomseed-io/bankster

```clj
(money/of :EUR 25)
; => #money[25.00 EUR]

(money/of 25 :EUR)
; => #money[25.00 EUR]

(money/of crypto/BTC 10.1)
; => #money/crypto[10.10000000 BTC]

(money/of BTC 10.1)
; => #money/crypto[10.10000000 BTC]

#money EUR
; => #money[0.00 EUR]

#money/crypto ETH
; => #money/crypto[0.000000000000000000 ETH]

#money[PLN 2.50]
; => #money[2.50 PLN]

#currency USD
; => #currency{:id :USD, :domain :ISO-4217, :kind :FIAT, :numeric 840, :scale 2}

(currency/symbol :USD)
; => "USD"

(currency/symbol :USD :en_US)
; => "$"

(currency/symbol :USDT)
; => "₮"

(currency/name :USDT)
; => "Tether"

(money/format #money[10 EUR])
; => "10,00 €"

(money/format #money[10 EUR] :en_US)
; => "€10.00"

(money/format #money[10 EUR] :pl {:currency-symbol-fn currency/name})
; => "10,00 euro"
```